# what is a vector dot del in cylindrical coordinates? $\vec{U}\cdot \nabla$

Tags: vectors, cylindrical-coordinates

what should be the product of :

$\vec{U}\cdot \nabla$  in a cylindrical coordinate ? for example with a scalar following the product such as $(\vec{U}\cdot \nabla) \Omega$ ? Thank you

Comment: does [the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates#Del_formula) answer your question?

Comment: yeah i checked there before i asked. Obviously they only gave the case where the following term is a vector, but I would like to know what it's like when followed by a scalar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The directional derivative in cylindrical coordinates.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1675872/the-directional-derivative-in-cylindrical-coordinates)

Answer (score 0):

$\renewcommand\phi\varphi$

The question already has answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1516780/an-expression-for-nabla-in-cylindrical-coordinates?rq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1675872/the-directional-derivative-in-cylindrical-coordinates?rq=1). However, those answers only treat the case when one is using an orthonormal basis $\{e_r,e_\phi,e_z\}$. In that case the gradient vector is
$$\nabla f = \partial_rf \,e_r + \frac 1 r \partial_\phi f \,e_\phi +\partial_zf \,e_z$$
So for a vector $u=u_re_r+u_\phi e_\phi+u_ze_z$ you have
$$\begin{align*}
u\cdot \nabla f
&= u_r\partial_rf \, e_r\cdot e_r
  + u_\phi\frac 1 r\partial_\phi f \, e_\phi\cdot e_\phi
  + u_z\partial_zf \, e_z\cdot e_z \\
&= u_r\partial_rf + u_\phi\frac 1 r\partial_\phi f+u_z\partial_zf \\
&= \left(u_r\partial_r + u_\phi\frac 1 r\partial_\phi +u_z\partial_z\right)f
\end{align*}$$
Hence
$$u\cdot \nabla =u_r\partial_r + u_\phi\frac 1 r\partial_\phi +u_z\partial_z.$$

---

On the other hand, if you are using the holonomic basis $\{v_r,v_\phi,v_z\}$ (that is, $v_r=e_r, v_\phi=re_\phi, v_z=e_z$), then the gradient vector is
$$\nabla f = \partial_rf \, v_r + \frac 1 {r^2}\partial_\phi f \, v_\phi +\partial_zf \, v_z$$
So for a vector $u=u_rv_r+u_\phi v_\phi+u_zv_z$ you have
$$\begin{align*}
u\cdot \nabla f
&= u_r\partial_rf \, v_r\cdot v_r
  + u_\phi\frac 1 {r^2}\partial_\phi f \, v_\phi\cdot v_\phi
  + u_z\partial_zf \, v_z\cdot v_z \\
&= u_r\partial_rf + u_\phi\partial_\phi f+u_z\partial_zf \\
&= \left(u_r\partial_r + u_\phi\partial_\phi +u_z\partial_z\right)f
\end{align*}$$
(the middle factor goes away because $v_\phi\cdot v_\phi=r^2$). Hence
$$u\cdot \nabla =u_r\partial_r + u_\phi\partial_\phi +u_z\partial_z.$$

Again please note that these formulas only hold when the directional derivative operator $u\cdot \nabla$ is applied to a scalar.

Comment: You have a bunch of $\frac{1}{\varphi}$ factors, all of which should be $\frac{1}{r}$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks a lot for noticing! I'm dumb sometimes. Anyway, do you think it is a good idea to migrate my answer to one of the older questions and mark this one as duplicate?